# Graphical representation of complex numbers using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Can anyone draw this graph in LaTeX using the Ti*k*Z package?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes, many users here can draw such diagrams. Notice, however, that the purpose of this site is to exchange codes and not let others draw diagrams for you. Anyway, as you are new here, here's a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw (0,-3) -- (0,4);
\draw (0,0) -- (15:3) node[right]{$z_1$}-- ++(75:3) node[above right]{$z_1+z_2$};
\draw (0,0) -- (75:3) node[above]{$z_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use TikZ `calc` library *(see p 142 of the manual 3.0.1a)* which allows you to make calculations on the points considered as **vectors** of origin `(0,0);`

For example, here, the affix point z3 is the sum of z1 and z2:

```
\coordinate (z3) at ($(z1)+(z2)$);
```

[image: vecteurs]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb]
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,4);
\coordinate(O)at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$z_1$](z1)at (3,1);
\coordinate[label=left:$z_2$](z2)at (1,3);
\coordinate (z3) at ($(z1)+(z2)$);
\draw (O)--(z1);
\draw (O)--(z2);
\draw(z1)--(z3)node[above right]{$z_1+z_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```